# The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation firestore permission denied

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Authentication.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:loginfirebase/DatabaseManager/DatabaseManager.dart';

class AuthenticationServices {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // Registration with EMail and Password

  Future createNewUser(String name,String email, String password) async{
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User? user = result.user;
      await DatabaseManager().createUserData(name, "Male", 500, user!.uid);
      return user;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  // Signin with email and password

  Future loginUser(String email, String password) async{
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      return result.user;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  //signout

  Future SignOut() async{
    try {
      _auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

DataBaseManager.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
class DatabaseManager{
    final CollectionReference profileList = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("ProfileInfo");

    Future<void> createUserData(String name, String gender, int score, String uid) async{
        return await profileList.doc(uid).set({
           'name':name,
           'gender':gender,
           'score':score
        });
    }
}
```

W/Firestore(11919): (24.4.3) [WriteStream]: (3dbd3b2) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Keepalive failed. The connection is likely gone, cause=null}.

W/Firestore(11919): (24.4.3) [WriteStream]: (3dbd3b2) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}.

W/Firestore(11919): (24.4.3) [Firestore]: Write failed at ProfileInfo/vsk5SFSH0OQqVtloHz86xQmHKWh2: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

I/flutter (11919): [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

This error is showing while signing up, Signup is successfully but data is not storing in firestore.

Rule Firestore

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Most likely your Firestore rules do not allow this operation in `ProfileInfo` collection. Either check your rules or add them to your question if you need help.

Comment: firestore rule added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Firestore rules disallow all read or write operations, that's why your `createUserData` fails with the insufficient permissions error message.

Strictly for testing, try to change this in the rules:

```
allow read, write: if true;
```

**BE CAREFUL!** This will allow all read and write operations to all of your collections to anybody.

Most likely, you want to restrict access, for example to authenticated users, and further, like don't allow operations to `ProfileInfo` if the `uid` is different from the user`s who is logged in.

So for production version, add another `match` rule for `ProfileInfo`, for example:

```
match /ProfileInfo/{uid} {
  allow read:, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid
}
```

You can fine tune these rules according to your use case.

Move current `match /{document=**}` after this new rule!

Comment: You are welcome, please consider marking my answer accepted if it helped you with your issue.

Comment: check this one please https://stackoverflow.com/q/75636091/19521776