# GridView builder in flutter from list of array

Tags: android, flutter

```
 Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: (){},
                child: Container(
                  width: 130,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    color: MyTheme.creamColor,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                          child: Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/icons.png"))
                        ),
                      // SizedBox(height: 7,),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text("Neurology"),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ),
              ),
            )
```

```
List of Names List<String>name = ["Neurogy","Dentist","Eye","Ear"];
```

Images in folder with name

cat1.png,  cat2.png,  cat3.png,  cat4.png

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVbCE.jpg) This is the output which I'm Expecting

Name length is not only 4 and same for image its total 24,
Complete code: https://github.com/reyaz-mra/flutter-firebase/blob/main/category.dart
How can i make it using Gridview builder in flutter??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like category name and asset path are the only two things that are changing. I'd recommend creating two lists:

- `List<String> categories`
- `List<String> assetPaths`

and using them in GridView like this:

```dart
GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2, // decides number of columns
        shrinkWrap: true, // clear space issue
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        children: List.generate(categories.length, (index){
          return InkWell(
                onTap: (){},
                child: Container(
                  width: 130,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    color: MyTheme.creamColor,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                          child: Image(image: AssetImage(assetPaths[index]))
                        ),
                      // SizedBox(height: 7,),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(categories[index]),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ),
              );
        }),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: ════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#a09d0 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 2009 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold

Comment: complete code: https://github.com/reyaz-mra/flutter-firebase/blob/main/category.dart

Comment: do you want heading text to be scrollable as well? or you just want the grid to be scrollable?

Comment: I've updated the code. Please wrap `SingleChildScrollView` inside a container with `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`

Comment: i just want grid scrollable

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it with `List.generate(length, (index)=> )` or using `name.map( (element) => )`

here how your code will look like

```dart
               Column(
                      children: List.generate(name.length, (index) => Column(children:Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                          child: Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/icons.png"))
                        ),
                      // SizedBox(height: 7,),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(name[index),
                        ) ))




                    ),
```

or you can achieve it like this with  `List.map` which is not recommended as it costs performance

```
           Column(
                  children: name.map((element)=> Column(children:Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                      child: Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/icons.png"))
                    ),
                  // SizedBox(height: 7,),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(element,
                    ) ))
                ),
```

Comment: full error is showing

Comment: check my complete code:https://github.com/reyaz-mra/flutter-firebase/blob/main/category.dart